# Using phpSASS Compass Extension

Tags: php, compass-sass

I'm struggling to use the phpSASS compass extension.

I'm using the following code to create my css files, but it doesn't work when I try to `@import` anything from Compass:

```
require_once("libs/phpsass/SassParser.php");

$options = array(
'style' => 'nested',
'cache' => FALSE,
'syntax' => 'scss',
'debug' => TRUE,
'extensions' => array('Compass','Own')
);

$sass = new SassParser($options); 
$css = $sass->toCss( $scssFolder."/".$scssFile );

file_put_contents($cssFolder."/".$cssFile, $css);
```

Where am I going wrong?

NB. If I don't use Compass mixins then it works fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the way in which it "doesn't work"?